# How to access multiple database schemas from single persistence unit?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am working on a project in which currently I have single persistence unit file as I have only one database schema there in my db. Now I need to separate that schema into two different schema. So I made two different ORM files and mapped it into the PU. Now when i build my EJB project its working fine but as soon as I build my WEB project it starts giving me compilation error.

So, is there any other way so that I can manage two different schema together??

Note that both the schema are related with foreign keys.

Please help me out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post those errors and maybe also the relevant parts of your Maven pom.xml :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Oracle and you have SCHEMA_1 and SCHEMA_2 **and you can define synonyms**:

- As SCHEMA_2, grant the appropriate privileges to SCHEMA_1
- Define synonyms in SCHEMA_1 for the tables in SCHEMA_2
- Now in SCHEMA_1 you should be able to use SCHEMA_2 tables as if they were there